# Iframe submits and user is redirected back to original page, but iframe still appears to be present?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have some JavaScript that spawns an iframe which requires the user to fill out some details. After they submit the iframe form, they are redirected to where they were previously; however, the iframe appears to still be present as right clicking in firefox brings up "This Frame" options. In addition, I am unable to click links or anything on the page.

On the other hand, if I include a function that closes the iframe after the form submits, the user is again redirected back to the original page, but there are no right click "This Frame" options this time and all the links on the page can be clicked.

Can anyone explain to me what is going on here? Thanks!

Comment: How are you redirecting? Using JavaScript?

Comment: I'm not performing any redirection myself. The form posts the data to a PHP script and then the spawned iframe appears to close, which takes the user back to the original page. However, in the first example, they are unable to click links and right clicking brings up the "this frame" options.

Comment: See my answer, was that (Second case) what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

If using Javascript to redirect, try adding this in front of the redirection:

```
window.top.location.href = "http://www.site.com";
```

Else, use `target="_top"`:

```
<form action".." target="_top">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I probably should have made it more clear in my question but I'm not actually looking for any code, I was just wondering what was going on with regards to the mechanics of it all in the first scenario. Is the iframe still there, but as the form has been submitted there is no content to it, so it just forms an invisible window over the original page? Purely speculating but this was what I was wondering!

Comment: Could you copy your code to jsfiddle.net, so that I may understand the scenario a little better?

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/qcpfS/ - as you can see I'm trying to dynamically change the form action. That example doesn't include the iframe close function, so if you were to run that you would be unable to click the links on the original page after the MyPage.php had been submitted. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: also fyi, this is it with a function to close the iframe included: http://jsfiddle.net/rxtUb/1/

Comment: Unfortunately I only see a broken page..
"http://127.0.0.1/MyPage.php" is a local link, do you have a webserver to put it on, so that the page doesnt break?